# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int com.google.android.material.timepicker.TimeModel.hour' on a null object reference

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I was making android alarmmanager app with notification using this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n9FN0odXqi0&ab_channel=Foxandroid , but I got an error When I tried to select the time. Attempt to read from field 'int com.google.android.material.timepicker.TimeModel.hour' on a null object reference
MainActivity.kt

```
package com.mahidev.alarmmanagernotification

import android.app.AlarmManager
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.android.material.timepicker.MaterialTimePicker
import com.google.android.material.timepicker.TimeFormat
import com.mahidev.alarmmanagernotification.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import java.util.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()
{

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var picker: MaterialTimePicker
    private lateinit var calendar: Calendar
    private lateinit var alarmManager: AlarmManager
    private lateinit var pendingIntent: PendingIntent

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        setContentView(binding.root)

        createNotificationChannel()

        binding.selectTimeBtn.setOnClickListener {
showTimePicker()
        }

        binding.setAlarmBtn.setOnClickListener {
                setAlarm()
        }

        binding.cancelAlarmBtn.setOnClickListener {
            cancelAlarm()
        }
    }

    private fun cancelAlarm() {
        alarmManager = getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        val intent = Intent(this, AlarmReciever::class.java)

        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,intent,0)

        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent)

        Toast.makeText(this,"Alarm Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG,).show()
    }

    private fun setAlarm()
    {
        alarmManager = getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        val intent = Intent(this,AlarmReciever::class.java)
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,intent,0)
        alarmManager.setRepeating(
            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.timeInMillis,
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent
        )

        Toast.makeText(this,"Alarm set Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    }

    private fun showTimePicker()
    {
        picker = MaterialTimePicker.Builder()
            .setTimeFormat(TimeFormat.CLOCK_12H)
            .setHour(12)
            .setMinute(0)
            .setTitleText("Select Alarm Time")
            .build()

        picker.show(supportFragmentManager, "foxandroid")

        picker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener {
            if(picker.hour > 12)
            {
                binding.selectTimeBtn.text = String.format("%02d", picker.hour - 12) + ":" + String.format("%02d", picker.minute)+"PM"
            }
            else
            {
                String.format("%02d", picker.hour - 12) + ":" + String.format("%02d", picker.minute)+"AM"
            }
        }
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        calendar[Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY] = picker.hour
        calendar[Calendar.MINUTE] = picker.minute
        calendar[Calendar.SECOND] = 0
        calendar[Calendar.MILLISECOND] =0
    }

    private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {
            val name: CharSequence = "foxandroidReminderChannel"
            val description = "Channel for Alarm Manager"
            val importance= NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            val channel = NotificationChannel("foxandroid",name, importance)

            channel.description = description
            val notificationManager = getSystemService(
                NotificationManager::class.java
            )

            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)

        }
    }
}
```

stacktrace

```
Process: com.mahidev.alarmmanagernotification, PID: 4854
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int com.google.android.material.timepicker.TimeModel.hour' on a null object reference
        at com.google.android.material.timepicker.MaterialTimePicker.getHour(MaterialTimePicker.java:125)
        at com.mahidev.alarmmanagernotification.MainActivity.showTimePicker(MainActivity.kt:97)
        at com.mahidev.alarmmanagernotification.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda-0(MainActivity.kt:36)
        at com.mahidev.alarmmanagernotification.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$GM5hRVkkZCzLwt-jP8T8_L8jiUw(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.mahidev.alarmmanagernotification.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: Move `picker.show(supportFragmentManager, "foxandroid")` after adding the listener.

Comment: I need to put picker.show after the adding listener code?

Comment: add it right before the `calendar = Calendar.getInstance()`

Comment: yeah. I did but no change.

Comment: Add relevant stacktrace.

Comment: thanks for the response. I have added just now.

Comment: whats on line 97?

Comment: calendar[Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY] = picker.hour

Comment: thats the one causing the crash.

Comment: okay. any solution

Comment: You are basically trying to set a calendar via pickers hour & minute, you should instead be setting values to picker as initial values from a calendar. Check this for example: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/material-design-time-picker-in-android/

Comment: thanks bro.. I am checking on it.

Comment: did you got any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

The following lines of code in the question needs to be part of `picker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener` body.

```
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar[Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY] = picker.hour
    calendar[Calendar.MINUTE] = picker.minute
    calendar[Calendar.SECOND] = 0
    calendar[Calendar.MILLISECOND] = 0
```

The final code will be

```
package com.mahidev.alarmmanagernotification

import android.app.AlarmManager
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.android.material.timepicker.MaterialTimePicker
import com.google.android.material.timepicker.TimeFormat
import com.mahidev.alarmmanagernotification.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import java.util.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()
{

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var picker: MaterialTimePicker
    private lateinit var calendar: Calendar
    private lateinit var alarmManager: AlarmManager
    private lateinit var pendingIntent: PendingIntent

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        setContentView(binding.root)

        createNotificationChannel()

        binding.selectTimeBtn.setOnClickListener {
showTimePicker()
        }

        binding.setAlarmBtn.setOnClickListener {
                setAlarm()
        }

        binding.cancelAlarmBtn.setOnClickListener {
            cancelAlarm()
        }
    }

    private fun cancelAlarm() {
        alarmManager = getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        val intent = Intent(this, AlarmReciever::class.java)

        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,intent,0)

        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent)

        Toast.makeText(this,"Alarm Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG,).show()
    }

    private fun setAlarm()
    {
        alarmManager = getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        val intent = Intent(this,AlarmReciever::class.java)
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,intent,0)
        alarmManager.setRepeating(
            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.timeInMillis,
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent
        )

        Toast.makeText(this,"Alarm set Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    }

    private fun showTimePicker()
    {
        picker = MaterialTimePicker.Builder()
            .setTimeFormat(TimeFormat.CLOCK_12H)
            .setHour(12)
            .setMinute(0)
            .setTitleText("Select Alarm Time")
            .build()

        picker.show(supportFragmentManager, "foxandroid")

        picker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener {
            if(picker.hour > 12)
            {
                binding.selectTimeBtn.text = String.format("%02d", picker.hour - 12) + ":" + String.format("%02d", picker.minute)+"PM"
            }
            else
            {
                String.format("%02d", picker.hour - 12) + ":" + String.format("%02d", picker.minute)+"AM"
            }
            
            calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
            calendar[Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY] = picker.hour
            calendar[Calendar.MINUTE] = picker.minute
            calendar[Calendar.SECOND] = 0
            calendar[Calendar.MILLISECOND] =0
        }
    }

    private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {
            val name: CharSequence = "foxandroidReminderChannel"
            val description = "Channel for Alarm Manager"
            val importance= NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            val channel = NotificationChannel("foxandroid",name, importance)

            channel.description = description
            val notificationManager = getSystemService(
                NotificationManager::class.java
            )

            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)

        }
    }
}
```